# Scraping and Looping with a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

The code below has a bug that I am unable to fix.

Code manages to copy successfully the **first 50 records** and paste them into my excel sheet from the table but the code doesn’t advance onwards past page 1 to all the other pages and repeat for all the other records.

I’d like the code to copy and paste all **111,582 records into my excel** sheet, not just do the first 50 records continuously.

Here is the code I have so far, which works to copy the data table on page one:

```
Sub LoopTest() 
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strText As String
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim hTable As Object
    Dim hBody As Object
    Dim hTR As Object
    Dim hTD As Object
    Dim tb As Object
    Dim bb As Object
    Dim tr As Object
    Dim td As Object
    Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    y = 1   'Column A in Excel
    z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel
    variable = 0

Here:
    ie.Navigate "website" & variable

    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = ie.Document
    Set hTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("conBody conList")

    For Each tb In hTable
        Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

        For Each bb In hBody
            Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tr In hTR
                Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                For Each td In hTD
                    ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
                    y = y + 1
                Next td
                DoEvents
                z = z + 1
            Next tr
            Exit For
        Next bb

        Exit For
    Next tb

    variable = variable + 1
    GoTo Here:
End Sub
```

Comment: You get only 50 records because there as only 50 records on that page. 
 You need to send a `Click` for next page.

Comment: Do you have a variable named `variable`?! **Please don't do that :'(**